# Approximating gradient using python

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, numerical-methods

I have attempted to solve the following problem.

For the calculation of gradient we are obliged to use an approximate calculation:

[image]

I tried to solve it for each vector e of the canonical basis of R^4 and using h = 1e-05 for example.

However, I made an example for R^2, but I'm not sure if my code is correct for this case and I need to change code for the formule in the picture.

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.sin(x)+np.cos(y)
def derivative(func, vx, h):
    e = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]]) #Basis canonique of R^2
    x = vx[0]
    y = vx[1]
    dx=(func(x + e[0]*h,y) - func(x,y)) / h #directional derivative in x
    dy=(func(x ,y+e[1]*h) - func(x,y)) / h #directional derivative in y
    grad = np.array([dx[0],dy[1]])
    return grad

vx=np.array([np.pi,1])
derivative(f,vx,h)
```

Results of this code:

```
In [150]: derivative(f,vx,h)
Out[150]: array([-1.        , -0.84147369])
```

I am a little confused how to do this problem but I was hoping to get some help with fixing the code I produced so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Review section 4.6 - Systems of Equations of the text below:

[Numerical Methods in Engineering with Python 3 (3rd ed.)](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/python/Numerical%20Methods%20in%20Engineering%20with%20Python%203%20%283rd%20ed.%29%20%5BKiusalaas%202013-01-21%5D.pdf)